# applying pivot table on pandas dataframe instead of grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this and can group it by library and sample columns and create new columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'barcode': ['b1', 'b2','b1','b2','b1', 
'b2','b1','b2'],
'library': ['l1', 'l1','l1','l1','l2', 'l2','l2','l2'],
'sample': ['s1','s1','s2','s2','s1','s1','s2','s2'],
'category': ['c1', 'c2','c1','c2','c1', 'c2','c1','c2'],
'count': [10,21,13,54,51,16,67,88]})
```

df

```
   barcode library sample category  count
0      b1      l1     s1       c1     10
1      b2      l1     s1       c2     21
2      b1      l1     s2       c1     13
3      b2      l1     s2       c2     54
4      b1      l2     s1       c1     51
5      b2      l2     s1       c2     16
6      b1      l2     s2       c1     67
7      b2      l2     s2       c2     88
```

I used grouping to reduce dimentions of the df:

```
grp=df.groupby(['library','sample'])

df=grp.get_group(('l1','s1')).rename(columns={"count": 
"l1_s1_count"}).reset_index(drop=True)
df['l1_s2_count']=grp.get_group(('l1','s2'))[['count']].values
df['l2_s1_count']=grp.get_group(('l2','s1'))[['count']].values
df['l2_s2_count']=grp.get_group(('l2','s2'))[['count']].values

df=df.drop(['sample','library'],axis=1)
```

result

```
barcode category    l1_s1_count l1_s2_count l2_s1_count  
l2_s2_count
0   b1  c1  10  13  51  67
1   b2  c2  21  54  16  88
```

I think there should be a neater way for this transformation, like using pivot table which I failed with, could you please suggest how this could be done with pivot table?
thanks.

Comment: Your output seems incorrect as there is no `l1_s2` combination in `b1, c1`?

Comment: I think in your code example `grp.get_group` needs to be replaced by `df_grouped.get_group` 3 times to be running, probably you had changed the variable name in between.

Comment: Sorry, now all updated.

Answer (score 2):

try pivot_table function as below,
it will produce multi-index result, which will need to be flattened.

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['barcode', 'category'], columns= ['sample', 'library'], values='count').reset_index()
df2.columns = ["_".join(a) for a in df2.columns.to_flat_index()]
```

out:

```
  barcode_ category_  s1_l1  s1_l2  s2_l1  s2_l2
0       b1        c1     10     51     13     67
1       b2        c2     21     16     54     88
```

or even without `, values='count'`.

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['barcode', 'category'], columns= ['sample', 'library']).reset_index()
df2.columns = ["_".join(a) for a in df2.columns.to_flat_index()]
```

out:

```
 barcode__ category__  count_s1_l1  count_s1_l2  count_s2_l1  count_s2_l2
0        b1         c1           10           51           13           67
1        b2         c2           21           16           54           88
```

as per your preference

Comment: works nicely, the NaN values should disappear now as I updated the originally posted df.

Comment: Yep, now the result is as you requested

Comment: I was able to avoid underlines after barcode and category column names with this: df2.columns = ['_'.join(str(a).strip() for a in col if a) for col in df2.columns]